# Javascript Logic Issue in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, function, logic

First I'll explain a little bit about my system here. It's a form to allow children to book onto a series of day courses that run in the school easter and summer breaks. The form allows registration of two children simultaneously, and if the dates for both children are the same, the sibling has a £5 discount for their dates.

On the form, there is a date section which is a series of checkboxes. As you check the checkboxes a total price is calculated at the bottom of the page.

The single child price is £29 and the sibling rate (for those dates that match up to the first child) is £24. There is an additional £16.50 charge for booking onto the horseriding course - but this logic error only extends to the date selection.

For some reason, which I cannot fathom, in Internet Explorer the price for registering 2 children appears £5 less that it should. Here is my code for calculating the dates (the function below is fired onclick of the date checkbox):

```
function processDates(){
    //contentsA and contentsB are used for outputting on the email confirmation
    valsA = [], dates_A =  document.forms['registerForm']['childADates[]'];
    for(var iA=0,elmA;elmA = dates_A[iA];iA++) {
        if(elmA.checked) {
            valsA.push(elmA.value);
        }
    }
    contentsA = valsA.join(', ');
    //this generates a string based on what dates were selected i.e. April 18th, April 19th etc.


    var valsB = [], dates_B =  document.forms['registerForm']['childBDates[]'];
    for(var iB=0,elmB;elmB = dates_B[iB];iB++) {
        if(elmB.checked) {
            valsB.push(elmB.value);
        }
    }
    contentsB = valsB.join(', ');
    //same as contentA but for the second child.

    //get the total dates for both children
    //fullDates is the number of dates selected (number of checkboxes checked)
    fullDates = (valsA.length + valsB.length);
    siblingDates=0;
    //this detects if entries are matching in the two arrays valsA and valsB
    for(var i in valsA) {
        for(var j in valsB) {
            if(valsA[i]==valsB[j]){
                            //if there are matching dates, increment a siblingDates value to get a total number of matching dates in the siblingDates variable
                siblingDates=siblingDates+1;
            }
        }
    }
    //get the amount of dates to be charged at £29
    fullDates = fullDates - siblingDates;

    fullPrice = fullDates*29;
    siblingPrice = siblingDates*24;
    totalPrice = fullPrice + siblingPrice;
    calcTotal();
}

function calcTotal(){
    var horseA = parseInt(document.getElementById("horseridingA").value);
    var horseB = parseInt(document.getElementById("horseridingB").value);
    var horse =  parseInt(horseA+horseB);
    //Add the horseriding price
    overall = parseFloat(horse*16.5)+totalPrice;
    //output the overall total to the form
    document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = overall;
}
```

**UPDATE:** This process is run when the user selects one of the checkboxes that correspond to each date. April 18th [], April 19th [] etc. These checkboxes are duplicated for the 2nd child. Upon clicking one of the checkboxes the above functions are run that calculate a total price at the bottom of the screen. In internet explorer, clicking a date for ChildA yields £24 not £29, but only on the FIRST date clicked, all other dates both childA and childB are calculated correctly. The first date choice is £5 less than it should be.

I just used IE to select the first date on the main child side and it gave £24, then unselected the same checkbox which gave £-5

**UPDATE 2:** Okay! I've narrowed down the problem to the below statement:

```
fullDates = (valsA.length + valsB.length);
siblingDates=0;
for(var i in valsA) {
alert(valsA[i]);
    for(var j in valsB) {
        if(valsA[i]==valsB[j]){
            alert("does equal");
            siblingDates=siblingDates+1;
        }else{
            alert("does not equal");
        }
    }
}
```

Upon clicking the April 18th checkbox, the first alert (valsA[i]) reads April 18th

The second alert reads "does not equal" as expected.

In Internet Explorer the above happens normally as expected but I get an additional set of alerts:

After the above 2 alerts I get a bizarre function alert that alerts of a string length error, it's about four lines of minified code so very difficult to decipher.

Then the same alert appears again.

Then I get "does equal"

Comment: I think this would be clearer with an example of what you're selecting on the form.  What's the exact situation of the form when you're seeing the error?

Comment: This process is run when the user selects one of the checkboxes that correspond to each date. April 18th [], April 19th [] etc. These checkboxes are duplicated for the 2nd child. Upon clicking one of the checkboxes the above functions are run that calculate a total price at the bottom of the screen. In internet explorer, clicking a date for ChildA yields £24 not £29, but only on the FIRST date clicked, all other dates both childA and childB are calculated correctly. The first date choice is £5 less than it should be

Comment: What is the value of contentsA and contents B?

Comment: They are just for the database entry and send mail in a different function, it would give a string of the combined dates i.e. April 18th, April 19th, April 20th etc. They aren't part of the faulty calculation.

Comment: I was just trying to see what was actually in them.  Remote debugging is hard! :)  You say they're not in the calculation but if you showed the value of those plus the value of fullDates,  and siblingDates before you subtract the sibling dates it would a lot easier to understand where things are going wrong.

Comment: I've updated the comments in the code to shed some light on each variable, cheers

Comment: That's good but what values do you see if you alert them?  Something weird is going on but we don't know where.  For example if anything goes wrong with the values, that would break the logic. If you're managing to get -5 then I suspect you're managing to get a sibling value of -1 somehow.

Comment: I'm getting a sibling value of 1 when NO sibling dates have been selected, so it's giving a value of £24 instead of £29. But unchecking processes the code correctly for some reason and deducts £29, hence the £-5

Comment: in which case please post what is in the contentsA and contentsB after you first click.

Comment: contentsA = April 18th Nothing in contentsB.

Comment: Ok, below  `if(valsA[i]==valsB[j]){`  add `alert(valsAi + '|' + valsB[j]);`

Comment: This error is bizarre. I've updated my code

Comment: what is the value of valsB[j] in the inner loop?  That array should be empty!

Comment: it is, but I think the weird error I've talked about is because I'm trying to loop through an empty array. It outputs the weird javascript function I talked about

Comment: Try the loops I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your loop to this:

```
for (var i=0; i < valsA.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j < valsB.length; j++) {
        if(valsA[i]==valsB[j]){
             alert("does equal");
             siblingDates=siblingDates+1;
        }else{
            alert("does not equal");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are a lifesaver! If I could upvote you a million times I would mate! Cheers

Comment: Excellent!  I wasn't going to let that bug beat me!  It turns out that using the for..in construct to loop through arrays is bad because it's really looping through their properties. Sometimes people add to the properties of the array object and that's properly what you were seeing when that weird alert happened.  Long story short... don't use for..in :D

Answer (score 0):

first up, these lines look wrong, is this how they appear in your code?

```
for(var iA=0,elmA;elmA = dates_A[iA];iA++)

  for(var iB=0,elmB;elmB = dates_B[iB];iB++)
```

try something like this

```
for(var iA=0;iA < dates_A.length;iA++){
var elmA = dates_A[iA];
...
}
```

Comment: Yeah. it creates 2 variables iA and elmA, elmA collects the data from dates_A and iA is the enumerator. This part works fine to return the correct dates. No Dates are missed out of these for statements

Comment: @Daniel: How do the loops terminate? In fact, it's because you're using an assignment in what should be a conditional. Assignment returns the new value, so `elmA = dates_A[iA]` does the assignment then evaluates to the new value of `elmA`. This will be `undefined` when you've run out of elements and the loop will stop. What an utterly _bizarre_ way to iterate an array.

Comment: Ok, I've not seen it done like that before :), try the more conventional way I've added for IE

Comment: What @longhairedsi said. Just iterate normally.

Comment: I've done that, and it still gives the same issue. The problem isn't with outputting the list of dates, that works fine, the issue is with calculating the total. Cheers anyway for helping me clean up my code!